# What is the meaning of "los sien"?

Tags: definiciones

> A short  while  later  I discovered that she  had  left  vases  filled  with  red roses all  over the  house, and a 
>   card  on  my  pillow: I  hope  you  reach  a  **hunnert**.

This is English translation by Grossman for the following section of Garcia Marquez's *Memories of My Melancholy Whores*:

> Poco después descubrí que había dejado floreros de rosas rojas por toda la casa, y
>   una tarjeta en la almohada: Le deseo que llegue a **los sien**.

As far as I can tell the author has translated "los sien" as "hunnert", which means [hundred](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hunnert). However, the term *sien* seems to mean [*temple*](https://translate.google.com/#es/en/sien), but Google Translate gives "one hundred" for [*los sien*](https://translate.google.com/#es/en/los%20sien). My first question is why has *los sien* been translated as *hunnert* and not *hundred* and the second question is, how come *sien* means *temple* and *los sien* means *hundred*?

Comment: Please notice that google translate gives you "one hundred" **but below** the box where you type whatever you want to be translated you see this message **"Showing translation for los cien"**.

Comment: Also, note this only works in dialects with [*seseo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_Spanish_coronal_fricatives). I pronounce "sien" and "cien" differently, so I was as confused as you until it hit me most people from Latin America would actually pronounce them the same.

Comment: @DGaleano sorry for missing that, you're right. Google Translate actually shows translation for *los cien*, though the Marquez actually used *sien*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The phrase correctly written is

> Le deseo que llegue a los **cien**.
>
> I hope you reach a hundred.

She is wishing he lives many more years and come to reach even a hundred years old. (I think this is a kind of farewell card).

As the narrative uses free indirect style, the narrator shows the message as she wrote it, that is, misspelling: *sien* (temple) instead of *cien* (a hundred). And therefore the translator put "hunnert" rather than "hundred"  to maintain the idea that the writer was not very cultured.

Comment: Thank you. It was very insightful to me to know that it has been misspelled intentionally and furthermore, the translator has conveyed the tone to some extent.